# How can I set up a single page that I display different contents depending on what link is selected in the navigation?

Tags: javascript, html

I want an easy way on a single html page to display contents depending what navigation link is selected on the page. For example, there may be many different types of content I want to show, but I want them only to display when a navigation link is selected. I prefer not to use very much CSS or Javascript because I have not become very familiar with those yet.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of keeping it on one page, using very little css and very little javascript, this is the best I can come up with. You can show and hide div elements on a single page depending what navigation link is selected. Normally we would not use inline styles, we would style with CSS. We also would normally use more styling on the divs instead of using linebreaks. However, in an effort to keep the CSS minimal as requested, I am presenting this solution. The javascript function could also be condensed by passing in (this) to the function rather than using multiple commands in the onclick, but let's keep it simple.

Notice the Pages below are each in their own div tags. We have a style on each of the div tags for the pages that is display:none, except for the default Home page because we want that to show when the page loads.

They also each have a class that is the same across all of them, and a class that is unique. By making a class that is the same we can hide them all. Since they also have a unique class we can show any one of them we want at any time.

STEP 1. you will create a div like the divs below for each of the pages

```
<!--The default home page is inside it's own div-->
<!--home page-->
<div class="content div-content-home">
  <strong>Home</strong><br/><br/>
  <span>
    welcome to our page, click the links below to learn more.
  </span>
</div>

<!--The first page is inside it's own div-->
<!--information about links to access for special info-->
<div class="content div-content-special"  style="display:none">
  <strong>Special Info</strong><br/><br/>
  <table border="1px solid">
    <tr>
      <td>description</td>
      <td>link</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some info</td>
      <td><a href="">a link to some info</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!--The second page is inside it's own div-->
<!--Contact Us-->
<div class="content div-content-contact" style="display:none">
  <span>
    <strong>Contact Us</strong><br/><br/>
    Brad Newsome<br/>
    1535 Simmons Rd<br/>
    Flower Mound, TX 75022<br/> 
  </span>
</div>

<!--The third page is inside it's own div-->
<!--About Us-->
<div class="content div-content-about" style="display:none">
  <span>
    <strong>More Information About Us</strong><br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </span>
</div>
```

Next we create a footer with links in it (don't use the margin-top or margin-left below, that was just to help with spacing so it looked better on this example

For each link, we have an associated div above. We have an onclick for each link here in the footer, and we do two things in the onclick. we hide all of the divs, then show the one they selected. be sure the class name matches the class name of the div above. example: div-content-home below must be the same as the associated div above with class div-content-home

STEP 2. you will create an associated link in the footer for each div, and add some onclick code to make the above div show or hide

```
<footer style="margin-top:100px;">
  <a style="margin-left:20px" href="#" onclick="hideAllContentDivs();document.getElementsByClassName('div-content-home')[0].style.display='block';">Home</a>  
  <a style="margin-left:20px" href="#" onclick="hideAllContentDivs();document.getElementsByClassName('div-content-special')[0].style.display='block';">Special Info</a>
  <a style="margin-left:20px" href="#" onclick="hideAllContentDivs();document.getElementsByClassName('div-content-contact')[0].style.display='block';">Contact Us</a>  
  <a style="margin-left:20px" href="#" onclick="hideAllContentDivs();document.getElementsByClassName('div-content-about')[0].style.display='block';">About Us</a>    
</footer>
```

Put this next function anywhere on the page. what this function does is it hides all of the divs before we show the one that the user selects in the footer. it hides them by using the class we assigned to all of them called content

```
<script>
function hideAllContentDivs(){
  var contentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
  for (var i = 0; i < contentDivs.length; ++i) {
      var div = contentDivs[i];  
      div.style.display='none';
  }
};
</script>
```

A working JSFiddle Example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7695Lwhz/).